# Accessing object via another object

Tags: java

I have three classes: `User`, `UserCategory`, and `PatientCase`.

Now, in some methods I need to check if the category or the case belong to the user who is currently logged in.

User:

```java
private Long id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String emailAddress;
private String password;
private Set<UserCategory> userCategories;
```

UserCategory:

```java
private Long id;
private String name;
private User user;
private Set<PatientCase> cases;
```

PatientCase:

```
private Long id;
private String caseTitle;
private LocalDate caseDate;
private Set<UserCategory> userCategories;
```

Now given a user and a category, I can check if the category does or does not belong to the user by doing this (in this case I am doing does not belong to the user):

```java
private boolean checkIfCategoryDoesNotBelongToUser(UserCategory category, User user) {
    return !category.getUser().getId().equals(user.getId());
}
```

The problem is how can I tell if the `PatientCase` does or does not belong to the user. And I am not allowed to add in any other fields to the classes. I was thinking of doing something like:

```java
private boolean checkIfCaseDoesNotBelongToUser(PatientCase patientCase, User user) {
    return !patientCase.getUserCategories()
            .stream()
            .filter(c -> c.getUser().getId().equals(user.getId()))
            .
```

Also I'm aware that filter doesn't actually return a boolean so maybe, `noneMatch`. But not really sure.

Basically, a patient case can belong to multiple categories. And a user can have multiple categories. Please suggest something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed use [`noneMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#noneMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-):

```
private boolean checkIfCaseDoesNotBelongToUser(PatientCase patientCase, User user) {
    return patientCase.getUserCategories()
        .stream()
        .noneMatch(c -> c.getUser().getId().equals(user.getId()));
}
```

`noneMatch` is short-circuiting, so it will return `false` as soon as one match is found.

---

Also, I suggest you not name your methods with a negative, so I'd rather write a `checkIfCaseBelongToUser` (use `anyMatch`!) and let the callers use `!` to negate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
public static Predicate < UserCategory > isUserIdPresent(Long id) {
         return uc -> uc.getUser().getId()== id;
}

public static  boolean checkIfCaseDoesNotBelongToUser(PatientCase patientCase, User user) {
        List<UserCategory> result  = patientCase.getUserCategories().stream().filter(isUserIdPresent(user.getId()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return !result.isEmpty();
}
```

With the help of predicate `isUserIdPresent` you can filter out those `userCategories` which have particular `user` present and collect the same in list.

And then just check if list size is greater than 0 and if it is it implies that particular user is present in `PatientCase`.